# Reflective Programming for use in Program Updates

Tags: java

Can reflective programming be used to update programs? For example if I wrote a Java game could I add new DLLs that might contain for example new characters and new types of weapons with new behaviors etc.

Comment: DLL = jar in Java land. Basically you're talking about doing a plugin system, right?

Comment: Thank you. I don't actually program in Java I am trying to research appropriate use cases for Reflective Programming. Essentially I am looking at if reflective programming could be used to extend a game beyond it's original feature set without updating the core game, providing the game was programmed with reflective in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go for **OSGI** as modular system with life-time management. Several OSGi containers like equinox exist. A jar module, called a bundle, can be dynamically loaded, and so on. And replaced with newer versions. That would provide the capability to *replace* and *add* functionality.
2. Otherwise if Java **WebStart** (JNLP) is still around: it provides an update mechanism via the internet.
3. One could use (URL-)ClassLoaders to dynamically load a class, say from a "features123" jar. That class could implement some interface (not be added to the jar!).

Comment: This sounds like an excellent approach, thank you for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 1):

Java dynamic class loading will allow you to do that. [This is a good tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html).

Answer (score 0):

OK, dll is not a good way to register/unregister objects in Java normally. Because it is "shared" system native library. when you register a dll, it is registered once and there is no way to UNLOAD it.

Of course you can add new native dll's via reflection api. Just beware about not to update existing one and do not change the methods/functions signature. It should behave like a plugin. Should not bother previous dlls and replace them also.